# Is it possible to filter out stream in Google Plus

Tags: google-plus

Hello I like Google plus, but the problem is that I am part of many communities and sometimes I just want to see what my friends (real people, not communities) post so I like to see a stream without many photos from "amazing places to see" for example so I don't miss out what my friends posted. I don't see any option to do that.

I tried setting up circles but the UI is clumsy - when you create a circle you cannot add people to it. It is only possible to display profiles one by one and choose which circles I want a person to be in.

Sadly you cannot do it for communities at all so posts from all communities I am member of always appears in "home" screen along with posts from people which I don't like. Maybe I am missing something...?

Comment: so it is not...